# Get array of combinations based on array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have the following array:

```
const arr = [
  {
    _id: '60c936bca0bd431287ae698b',
    name: 'Markets',
    referential: '60c936bca0bd431287ae6988'
  },
  {
    _id: '60c93b17a0bd431287ae69a0',
    name: 'eRetailers',
    referential: '60c93b17a0bd431287ae699f'
  },
  {
    _id: '60d0a30d303ebd2a19d6fb4d',
    name: 'Products',
    referential: '60d0a30d303ebd2a19d6fb4b'
  },
  {
    _id: '60c936bca0bd431287ae6989',
    name: 'Regions',
    referential: '60c936bca0bd431287ae6988'
  },
  {
    _id: '60d0a30d303ebd2a19d6fb4c',
    name: 'Segments',
    referential: '60d0a30d303ebd2a19d6fb4b'
  }
];
```

Now I want an array of all the possible combination of the array above, with one condition: a combination cannot contain two objects have the same referential.

Here is the full list of the desired combinations:

```
Aggregations level 1 :
Products
Segments
Markets
Regions
eRetailers

Aggregations level 2 :
Products/Markets
Products/Regions
Products/eRetailers
Segments/Markets
Segments/Regions
Segments/eRetailers
Markets/Products
Markets/Segments
Markets/eRetailers
Regions/eRetailers
Regions/Products
Regions/Segments
eRetailers/Markets
eRetailers/Regions
eRetailers/Products
eRetailers/Segments

Aggregations Niveau 3 :
Products/Regions/eRetailers
Products/eRetailers/Regions
Segments/Markets/eRetailers
Segments/eRetailers/Markets
Segments/Regions/eRetailers
Segments/eRetailers/Regions
Markets/eRetailers/Segments
Markets/Segments/eRetailers
Regions/Products/eRetailers
Regions/eRetailers/products
Regions/Segments/eRetailers
Regions/eRetailers/PSegments
eRetailers/Regions/Products
eRetailers/Products/Regions
eRetailers/Markets/Segments
eRetailers/Segments/Markets
eRetailers/Regions/Segments
eRetailers/Segments/Regions
```

Here's the current code which is not working properly:

```
function combinator (s) {
   list_of_strings = new Array();
   for(i=0;i<s.length;i++) {
       for(j=i+1;j<s.length+1;j++) {
           list_of_strings.push(s.slice(i, j));
       }
   }
   return list_of_strings;
}

console.log(combinator(arr));
```

Comment: I guess you could use FlatMap for this. Something like
`const result = arr.flatMap(
  (curVal, idx, myArr) => arr.slice(idx + 1).map(item => ``${curVal.name}/${item.name}` )
);`

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind, is that nowhere in your code any referentials are compared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my approach:

I've made a recursive parsing function (`parseLevel`) which, if the depth level has not been reached, is looking for any other item having a `ref` different than the ones already used. In order to achieve this, I pass it the following params:

- `refs` - already used `refs` (filtering),
- `ids`,
- `acc` - accumulator,
- `depth` - current depth level
- `level` - required number of items in a permutation

```js
const arr = [{
    _id: '60c936bca0bd431287ae698b',
    name: 'Markets',
    referential: '60c936bca0bd431287ae6988'
  },
  {
    _id: '60c93b17a0bd431287ae69a0',
    name: 'eRetailers',
    referential: '60c93b17a0bd431287ae699f'
  },
  {
    _id: '60d0a30d303ebd2a19d6fb4d',
    name: 'Products',
    referential: '60d0a30d303ebd2a19d6fb4b'
  },
  {
    _id: '60c936bca0bd431287ae6989',
    name: 'Regions',
    referential: '60c936bca0bd431287ae6988'
  },
  {
    _id: '60d0a30d303ebd2a19d6fb4c',
    name: 'Segments',
    referential: '60d0a30d303ebd2a19d6fb4b'
  }
];
const refIds = [...new Set(arr.map(({referential}) => referential))].map(ref => ({
  ref,
  _ids: arr.filter(({referential}) => referential === ref).map(({_id}) => _id)
}));

function getPermutations(level) {
  return refIds.reduce((acc, {ref, _ids}) => {
    _ids
      .forEach(id => parseLevel({
        depth: 1,
        level,
        refs: [ref],
        ids: [id],
        acc
      }));
    return acc;
  }, [])
}

function parseLevel({depth, level, refs, ids, acc}) {
  if (depth === level) {
    acc.push(ids.map(id => getItemName(id)).join('/'))
  } else {
    refIds
      .filter(({ref}) => !refs.includes(ref))
      .forEach(({ref, _ids}) => _ids
        .forEach(id => parseLevel({
          depth: depth + 1,
          level,
          refs: [...refs, ref],
          ids: [...ids, id],
          acc
        }))
      );
  }
}

function getItemName(id) {
  return arr.find(({_id}) => _id === id).name
}

console.log(Object.assign({}, 
  ...[1, 2, 3, 4].map(i => ({ [i + ' permutations']: getPermutations(i) })),
  { refIds }
))
```

Because the requirement is to create combinations of items with unique `ref`s, I start by creating an array of all distinct `ref`s: `refIds`. In each of them I'm also placing `ids` of all elements having that `ref`.
This step is not really necessary, but it ensures we don't iterate through items which would be excluded anyways (because they have the same `ref`).

I then start creating results by going through each `id` of each `refId` element, placing its `id` into `ids` (and its `ref` into `refs`) and then run `parseLevel`, which looks for any element having a `ref` not yet present in `refs`. If it finds one, it does the same: ads its `id` to `ids` and its `ref` into `refs`. Then it runs `parseLevel` again.
Each time it runs, it first checks if the desired depth `level` has been reached. If so, it transforms the `ids` into names, because that's what we want to present.

The obvious advantage is recursivity here: it means this will work with any number of different `refs` (therefore any number of `level`s).
The only condition I took for granted is that each element has a unique `_id`.